# Cannot close a custom AlertDialog

Tags: android-studio

so I have an app with three different buttons(parent buttons) on pressing any of them, the custom alert dialog with 9 different buttons is displayed but the functions of these 9 buttons within the alert dialog are different depending on which of the three parent buttons called it. On pressing any of the 9 buttons, I want the app to perform a particular function and then close the alertdialog. Now the problem is that I can easily call the alert dialog by calling the method `showcustomdialog();` that I created but I can't dismiss it using `alertdialog.dismiss();` inside the OnClickListener of the parent button since the method has a void result type. I've tried using if-else statements but it doesn't work. How can I achieve what is required?

The method:

```
    private void showCustomDialog() {
    ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_main2, viewGroup, false);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(dialogView);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
      }
```

I am calling the meathod and using it as follows:

```
    parentbutton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        showCustomDialog();
        alertbutton1.getId();
        alertbutton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textView1.setText("500");
                function();
             //I want to dismiss the alertdialog here.
            }
        });
        alertbutton2.getId();
        alertbutton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textView1.setText("1000");
                function();
             //I want to dismiss the alertdialog here.
            }
        });
```

and so on.

Comment: Did you try calling dismiss(); ?

Comment: It wont work because as i mentioned, the method showcustomdialog() has a void result type, i want to call the dismiss function outside of the showcustomdialog() meathod.

Comment: where did you get `alertbutton1` from? Is it part of dialog view?

Comment: yes, it is a part of the dialog view. I could have set the OnClickListeners for the buttons within the `showcustomdialog()` method but as i mentioned their function is different depending on which parent button calls the alertdialog so doing that is not an option.

Comment: But alertButton1 is not part of the view which was added to alertDialog. how have you initialized the alertButton1?

Comment: the button is a part of the layout 'layout.dialog_main2'

Comment: you can try with `builder.create().dismiss();`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution for you using AlertDialog.

```
  parentbutton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createDialog();
            }

        });
```

Then the method MUST be a private or public AlertDialog:

```
   private AlertDialog createDialog() {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (getActivity()).getLayoutInflater(); // for fragment or getLayoutInflater(); for activity
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_new_list, null);
    Button okButton = v.findViewById(R.id.confirm_button);
    Button cancelButton = v.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
    
    final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()) // for fragment or AlertDialog.Builder ( this ) for activity
        .setView(v)

        .show();
        
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                
        }
    });
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View p1) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }


        });
    
    return dialog;
    
}
```

P.S. Replace the ids I used to create this sample with yours.