# Close Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-studio

Close Alert Dialog on clicking the `Cancel` button is not working. `Dismiss()` is not working for `Alert/dialog`. Please suggest what to write in the `Onclick` button event.

```
 @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
           // Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enter number of households here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);


           final ViewGroup subview=(ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().
                             inflate(R.layout.edittext_info_dialog,null,false) ;
           TextView tv = (TextView) subview.findViewById(R.id.Info_Title);
           tv.setText("Enter number of household in village here");

           final AlertDialog.Builder builder=  new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());


                  builder.setView(subview);
                  builder .show();

                  

          Button Cancel=(Button) subview.findViewById(R.id.Cancel_Info);
          Cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
               Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Cancel",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               
              }
          });

            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you try the answer provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64630074/cannot-close-a-custom-alertdialog?noredirect=1#comment114277836_64630074

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you, not builder dismiss

first, change line code

```
   final AlertDialog builder=  new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
```

and you can `dismiss` or `cancel` dialog

```
  @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         Toast.makeText(getc.this,"Cancel",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         builder.dismiss();
      }
```